# CSS :focus not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, pseudo-class

I tried using `:focus` `CSS` pseudo-class in my project. I want to change the color of the element where I click on it. Now when I click my element change color only where it is active and after mouse up it return to old color. After second click I want it back to old color. I'm using Chrome.

**Demo** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uuyNH/29/)

```css
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 1em;
  background: grey;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.row:active,
.row:focus {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced you can focus something that's not "an interaction element", i.e. a link, input, button or somesuch.

Comment: :focus only goes on when the element has focus; as soon as you mouse up the focus leaves the element.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you want a real focus state to a div element, you can add a `tabindex` attribute to it.

```css
.row {
 display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid grey;  
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height:1em;
  background: grey;
  margin: 5px;
   opacity: 0.1;
}

.row:active, .row:focus { background: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
<div class="row" tabindex="1" id="row0">
</div>
</div>
```

If you want toggle the color with clicking the same div element, you have to use javascript (jQuery):

```js
jQuery('#row0').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('orange');
});
```

```css
.row {
 display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid grey;  
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height:1em;
  background: grey;
  margin: 5px;
   opacity: 0.1;
}

.row.orange { background: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" class="container">
<div class="row" id="row0">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate the toggle effect with a CSS trick by adding a hidden checkbox input.

[See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/uuyNH/35/)

> HTML :

```
<div id="main" class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="row" id="row0">
  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS :

```
.container { position: relative; }
input { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px; z-index: 1; opacity: 0; display: block; }
input:checked + .row { background: orange; }
```

Comment: But in case if I want after second click return to old color, how I can do this?

Comment: You can't with CSS. You'll have to add a listener with JS or jQuery, that will toggle a class based on the current class.

Comment: @Rvervuurt Can you give me an example?

Comment: @DanteVoronoi I've edited my answer with a CSS solution. But otherwise, you can use javascript to a more "proper" way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Following Andy Tschiersch's answer, I would suggest using tabindex = "0" (which is its default value) instead of tabindex = "1".

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row0" tabindex="0" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid grey;  
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height:1em;
  background: grey;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.row:active, .row:focus { background: orange; opacity:1 }
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
<div class="row" tabindex="1" id="row0">
</div>
</div>
```

Please try this...

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is `:visited`, but this doesn't work on a div. You should use the `a`-tag for it (including `href="#"`).

```
.row:active, .row:visited { background: orange; }
```

Check the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/uuyNH/32/

Edit: Vincent G's answer seems to do more what you want though, since you can remove the background color by clicking away.

Comment: I forgot about one behavior. After second click I want return to old color and `:visited` in this case is not work.