# This simple focus: snippet or toggleClass script alternative are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Wordpress (latest version) I have this image I want to rotate when it's focused. I tried : focus but it did not work. Also tried class toggling as an alternative but somehow neither work...

1- I gave class ' Rotate45 ' to this image and wrote down this CSS

```
.Rotate45 {
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

.Rotate45:focus {
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I don't understand why it does not work... if I replace :focus by :active or just remove :focus altogether it behaves as expected, but somehow not with :focus. I added attribute tabindex|1 as well but it fixes nothing.

2-As the focus: was not working, as an alternative, I replaced the first instance of Rotate45 by Rotate, changed the image class to Rotate, replaced Rotate45:focus by Rotate45, then added an HTML widget with the following toggleclass code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".Rotate").click(function() {
  $(".Rotate").toggleClass("Rotate45");
});
</script>
```

And still nothing, it's frustrating. Any help would be much appreciated [Here is a link to the test page for reference.](https://blueprint.devops.unlimitedgrowth.io/test)

PS: Am a total coding rookie and would like to learn some JS, PHP and JQuery

Comment: There is no element on the linked page with a `Rotate` or `Rotate45` class. Please provide a [MRE] _within your question_.

Comment: Link updated, did not realize a login was required for the previous link, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used [:focus](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) event for css which is used when you are dealing with input controls, you should use `:hover` event like below, click on green square and it will transform

```js
$(".Rotate").click(function() {
  $(".Rotate").toggleClass("Rotate45");
});
```

```css
.Rotate45 {
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

.Rotate45:hover {
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color:red;
}
.Rotate{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Rotate"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but the expected behavior is for it to rotate when after the element is clicked and if possible until the user clicks something else (hence me trying to use focus).

The JS that switches the element class from non rotated to rotated does not work at all on the test site for some reason...

Comment: To be clear, I think the problem with this snippet is that the JS snippet you provide (the same I used before) does not work on the test site for some reason

Comment: you can still use focus but you have to use tabindex="1" attribute on div - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741709/css-focus-not-working

Comment: I see thanks, I was trying to use that directly on the element not on the div before no wonder it did not work -_- !! that was very helpful